# How to read a space-delimited text file and save it to Hive?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-1.6

I have a string like below. The first row is the header, and the rest are the column values.
I want to create a dataframe (Spark 1.6 and Java7) from the String , and convert the values under col3 and col4 as DOUBLE .

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
val1 val2 val3 val4 val5
val6 val7 val8 val9 val10
val11 val12 val13 val14 val15
```

After creating the dataframe for the above , i have two fields to be in the first row whose values are constants.

```
const1 const2 col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
const1 const2 val1 val2 val3 val4 val5
const1 const2 val6 val7 val8 val9 val10
const1 const2 val11 val12 val13 val14 val15
```

I want to write the above dataframe to hive table with the schema (const1 int, const2 int, col1 double, col2 double , col3 double , col4 double, col5 double).
I'm using Spark 1.6 and Java7 .

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend using the latest and greatest [Spark 2.1.1](http://spark.apache.org/news/spark-2-1-1-released.html) that supports CSV files out of the box.

---

Unless I'm mistaken CSV support in Spark 1.6 is by using [spark-csv](https://spark-packages.org/package/databricks/spark-csv) package.

Start your Spark environment with the package loaded:

```
--packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.5.0
```

and that gives you csv format support.

From the package's [homepage](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv#java-api):

```
SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc);
DataFrame df = sqlContext.read()
    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")  // <-- enables csv support in Spark SQL
    .option("inferSchema", "true")
    .option("header", "true")
    .load("cars.csv");
```

You'd have to use `delimiter` option since it defaults to the comma.

> **delimiter** by default columns are delimited using `,`, but `delimiter` can be set to any character

With the file loaded as a DataFrame you can add the constant columns using [DataFrame.withColumn](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.3/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.html#withColumn(java.lang.String,%20org.apache.spark.sql.Column)) method:

> `public DataFrame withColumn(String colName, Column col)`
>
> Returns a new DataFrame by adding a column or replacing the existing column that has the same name.

Once done, saving to Hive is just a matter of using `write()` method of your `SQLContext` and:

```
write().saveAsTable(tableName)
```

See [DataFrame API](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.3/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.html).

Answer (score 0):

Since you have all the required data on a file, and the columns you want to append are constants, this can also be done using a simple case class and `createDataFrame` in Scala. Providing a scala related solution which might help you understand how you should approach for the solution

```
case class schema (const1: Int, const2: Int, col1: String, col2: String, col3: String, col4: String, col5: String)
//Skip Header while loading the data
val fileRDD = sc.textFile("file")
                .mapPartitionsWithIndex{ (index, row) => if (index==0) row.drop(1) else row }
                .map(x => x.split(" "))
                .map(x => schema(1, 2, x(0), x(1), x(2), x(3), x(4) ))
val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(fileRDD)
df.show()    
+------+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|const1|const2| col1| col2| col3| col4| col5|
+------+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|     1|     2| col1| col2| col3| col4| col5|
|     1|     2| val1| val2| val3| val4| val5|
|     1|     2| val6| val7| val8| val9|val10|
|     1|     2|val11|val12|val13|val14|val15|
+------+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

And loading data to hive, as Jacek has mentioned:

> Once done, saving to Hive is just a matter of using write() method of your SQLContext and:

```
write().saveAsTable(tableName)
```

> See [DataFrame API](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.3/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.html).